# Value change with ruamel yaml won't work and ignores indenting

Tags: python-2.7, indentation, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

I have a problem with dumping data back to YAML with correct format. Looked into other similar questions but didn't find solution for this problem.
Current code in Python:

```
template = yaml.load(open(templateFile), Loader=yaml.RoundTripLoader)

template["key"] = new_value

yaml.dump(template, sys.stdout, Dumper=yaml.RoundTripDumper, indent=2)
```

Input:

```
parameters:
  key: value
```

Output:

```
parameters:
  key: value
key: new_value
```

Expected output:

```
parameters:
  key: new_value
```

How should the code be modified, to either change the old "key" value, or enter a new one with correct indenting?

Comment: "Looked into other similar questions" include links and explanations of why not please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to assign the `new_value` to the right mapping/dict:

```
import sys
from ruamel import yaml

template_file = 'input.yaml'
new_value = 'new_value'

template = yaml.load(open(template_file), Loader=yaml.RoundTripLoader)
template['parameters']['key'] = new_value
yaml.dump(template, sys.stdout, Dumper=yaml.RoundTripDumper, indent=2)
```

a new value indented "under" `key` would require:

```
template['parameters']['newkey'] = 'added_value'
```

please note that it is customary to use snake_case for Python variables like `template_file` (`RoundTripLoader`/`RoundTripDumper` are the names of  classes)